# Safely modifying variable in two threads

Tags: c, windows, unix, thread-safety, pthreads

Consider the following contrived examples-

Say I have a thread that modifies a global variable:

```
void thread_1(void* param) {
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        x += i; // x is global.
    }
}
```

And say I have another thread that modifies the same global variable:

```
void thread_2(void* param) {
    while (1) {
        x = 0; // x is global.
        usleep(20000);
    }
}
```

How do I pause the second thread's execution to wait until the first thread is finished executing to continue execution in the second thread safely to prevent a race condition from occurring?

Comment: use a pthread barrier https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_barrier_init

Comment: do you mind providing an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create threads for example 6 threads you dont need to use 6 functions for that like you did , void thread1 and thread2.you must create them like :

```
pthread_mutex_t lock= PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;   // this locks the critical arrea
pthread_cond_t  consum = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER; // and this is a conditional variable
    pthread_t consumerN[2];
    
    //then in your main function 
    int main(){
           
          
          pthread_create(&consumerN[1],NULL,thread_1,NULL);// go to thread_1
          pthread_create(&consumerN[2],NULL,thread_2,NULL);//go to thread_2
           
    }
    void thread_1(int *param){
       pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
       pthread_cond_wait(&consum,lock);
       for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
           x += i; // x is global.
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
   }
   void thread_2(int *param){
       pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
       pthread_cond_wait(&consum,lock);
       
      while(1){
          x=0;
          sleep(2000);


      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
  }
```

Comment: `thread_2` and `thread_1` modify the `x` variable differently that's why I'm using two different threads. Could you provide an example where two threads that modify `x` differently use locks? And also how would one achieve this using the windows/winsock api?

Comment: @daskin_i334 i give you two simple examples to use locks , i dont have enough info from your code but  if you use two different function to modify the variable x why you need to lock ?  thread_1 and thread_2 is Function not threads  how do you know that many  the threads that are you talking about is runing the same arrea at the same time ? give me more info about that

Comment: They're just contrived examples, I need to know how to safely modify a variable within two threads without critical race conditions. I'm just making sure I can apply your original answer to `thread_1` and `thread_2` and that there was no miscommunication or misunderstandings.

Comment: @daskin_i334 check again i edit what i write before i hope this will be more helpfull to you

Comment: Do you know which windows/winsock apis do the same logic?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add mutex.When a mutex try to  run in a critical area the other have to wait so.Create a mutex that stops the threads

```
pthread_mutex_t lock= PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  consum = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void function(){ //were the mutex is trying to run 
 pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
 pthrad_cond_wait(&consum,lock);// this is saying  that : only one at a time
 
  //critical area


  //here you can use signals to let the other threads when this current thread is funish.
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);// when a thread unlock's the  mutex then the other starting to run the critical area

}
```

Comment: Is this for multiple threads executing the same function? Should I add the locks to both threads or just one?

Comment: @daskin_i334  yes !

Comment: @daskin_i334 check again i had forgot to add condition  in critical arrea

Comment: Do you mind apply this method to my examples above for readability ?

Comment: @daskin_i334  in my example were i say // critical arrea there you must put your for loop or while loop

Comment: Do you know the windows equivalents to the `pthread_mutex_lock`, `pthrad_cond_wait` and `pthread_mutex_unlock`?